# Symfony process submitted form

Tags: symfony

I have a general question how the currently correct way of processing a submitted form should look like, the symfony docs aren't that clear what's the proper way to go.
Currently I am always doing something like this:

```
if ($request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)) {
   $form->handle($request)
   if ($form->isValid()) {...}
}
```

but I have also seen some examples (also in the symfony docs) where this statement is used:

```
$form->handle($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {...}
```

So does anyone know what's the currently correct way to go following symfony developer guidelines, should the first statement be used or second, or should both be combined (although this would make either the $request->isMethod call or the $form->isSubmitted redundant)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically all you need is:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    ...
}
```

That's because:

- the `isValid()` check includes the `isSubmitted` check.
- the `isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)` check is not necessarily correct (a form can use a different method than `POST`

But if you really want to follow best practices, you should use:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    ...
}
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#handling-form-submits for details.

## Additional info

You may want to use the `isSubmitted` method separately if you want to perform some special task **before** the data is actually validated. I use it often for custom validations, e.g.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    ...
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general both is correct.
Just first example has check of request type when second simply check for submit and doing validation.

Comment: I know that both work, but there must be a guideline which one is the "standard" code styling

Comment: First sample just check request method -- POST/GET/PUT etc. In this example if request is not POST method form won't be processed. In second  sample -- form will be processed with any request method so it simply uses `$form->isSubmitted()`. It's a same thing like this:
`if ($request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)||$request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_GET))...`. So in second simply omitted this check.